# How to find max value

Tags: python, max

I do not know what is wrong with the code.

```
def FunMax(theNumList):
    theMax = 0
    for Num in theNumList:
        if theMax < Num:
            theMax = Num
            return theMax

nList  = [100.11,123,456,234,111,321,60,99,88]

test4 = FunMax(nList)
print(test4)
```

Comment: So what is wrong with it? Does it give you an error? Or does it work, but not as you expected? What is the expected behavior and the actual behavior?

Comment: @PikachuthePurpleWizard it looks like you fixed the code when you edited the question

Comment: @t-boeck thank you so much for catching that! I was reviewing a suggested edit and didn't realize it modified the return statement indentation.

Answer (score 1):

The return statement is at the wrong level. It must be outside of the for loop so the code can go through the whole list.

One caveat is that it won't return the max value of the list if all values are < 0.

```
   def FunMax(theNumList):
        theMax = 0

        for Num in theNumList:
            if theMax < Num:
                 theMax = Num
        return theMax
```